# Background-image: url() seems don't work with Github deploy

Tags: github, url, deployment, path, background-image

- I been searching this solution for a while and i can't sill find any clue to solve the problem...
- background-img: url() work great with my local but when i deploy to Github, it's just a blank picture.
- I've checked everything like the path directory for the image, and I think that it's correct. I am not able to get where is the problem occuring and how to resolve it.

Thanks for all the help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGTtg.png)
^ up here is my screenshot to show the folder structure
v down here is my picture path worked in local:
`background-image: url("../../../assets/imgs/hotel.jpg")`

1. I have tried change the path like this (using slash and "." or without both):

```
../ or ../ or /
```

2. changed the format of the picture (case sensitive,etc..):

```
example.JPG or example.jp
```

even then i put the style attribute into hmtl...

but nothing seem to work with Github deploy pages (remind it worked in my local pc)

Comment: If possible, can you share a link to your repository? In which file are you using background url?

Comment: my pic file is .jpg with no case sensitive and i have showed this link: url("../../../assets/imgs/hotel.jpg") up there, but tks for the reply but i also solve the problem myself. I use a trick that u can use style atribute in html file with background-image and url ('./images/description-background.jpg'). this should be work 100% just leave Github a while to load the image.

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, you should write an answer and then accept it. This will help people facing the same issue in the future.

Comment: Thank you i have written my answer and accepted it, i really appreciate you with the time you spent for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I used a trick of setting the style attribute in the HTML file with `background-image` and `url ('./images/description-background.jpg')`. This should work 100%; just give GitHub a while to load the image.